# I want to create a trading view alert when price is near a support or resistance line

Tags: trading, tradingview-api

I am an IOS user and it appears it is only possible to create an alert when price has crossed a line (not when it is near), so i assume it would require some kind of custom script but i am a newbie so dont know how to do this!   Hoping there is an easy solution that I can leverage.  Thanks in advance

I have tried creating alerts in iOS but it only appears to allow these to trigger only when price has crossed a line, not when it is near